# Jmeter results not consistent and depend from the running machine

Tags: jmeter

I have a Jmeter scenario .jmx, i run it from my machine  and my collegue run it from his machine. both PC are totally equivalent and we have almost the same internet connection +- 50 M/s and we are using the same Jmeter version 5.4.1.
The probleme that we have totally different results:
1- the total samples are different 16000 vs 42000
2- the total errors are different 20% vs 5%
3- the nature of errors are different connection time out vs connection pool shut down

I run  the same scenario from a third PC of mine and i got again a different results and a probleme in the generated reports:
1- the total samples are different 3000!!!!
2- the total errors are different  5%
3- the nature of errors are different  connection pool shut down

the test run multiple time and give every time almost the same results for evry PC.
note : - We use bzm-Concurrence Thread Group
- We use the following configuration
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiXOP.png)

did some one faced the same probleme or have an explanation?

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you check the single-user experience from both machines through the Chrome developer too-> Network tab l?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing), i.e. JMeter is sending requests as fast as it can - then getting different number of sample results on different hardware is kind of expected as there could be a lot of varying factors like:

- operating system
- JVM version
- different JMeter configuration
- 3rd-party software having impact on JMeter and vice versa
- network impact (i.e. latency)
- etc.

If you want repeatability:

- pack your JMeter test into a container like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and make sure to [limit container's usage of host CPU, RAM, etc.](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)
- use this container instead of .jmx script on the machines (or even better deploy the container somewhere in the [cloud](https://searchcloudsecurity.techtarget.com/feature/Cloud-containers-what-they-are-and-how-they-work)
- be aware that real users don't hammer the system under test non stop as fast as they can, they need some time to "think" between operations so it might be a good idea to introduce [think-times](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers)

this way you should get the same load pattern no matter where you run your script.

Comment: the probleme that we have exactly (really exactly) the same PC.

Comment: and the scenario is for 8 min - 100 user -adding 20 user every 90s.